# Sorting out JSON data into a smaller file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large JSON file, I am trying to pull out specific key blocks but i am unsure on how to do this.

Current JSON file:

```
{
    "blockID1": {
        "name": "name here",
        "locale": "en_GB"
    },
    "blockID2": {
        "name": "name here",
        "locale": "en_GB"
    },
    "blockID3": {
        "name": "name here",
        "locale": "en_GB"
    },
    "blockID4": {
        "name": "name here",
        "locale": "en_GB"
    }
}
```

I just want to retrieve blockID3 and blockID4 and then I would output into another json file.

```
{
       "blockID3": {
            "name": "name here",
            "locale": "en_GB"
        },
        "blockID4": {
            "name": "name here",
            "locale": "en_GB"
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array as a lookup and then loop over the object and if a key is found copy the value to the output object.

```js
var obj = {"blockID1":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID2":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID3":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID4":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"}};

var find = ['blockID3', 'blockID4'];
var out = {};

for (var p in obj) {
    if (find.indexOf(p) > -1) {
      out[p] = obj[p];
    }
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question but if you want to output something like that, and you have the ids of the json file if you want you could simply do something like this

```
    const props = ['blockID3', 'blockID4'],
          json = {"blockID1":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID2":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID3":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"},"blockID4":{"name":"name here","locale":"en_GB"}},
          res   = {};

    for(const prop of props) {
      if(json[prop]) { 
        res[prop] = prop;    
      }    
    });
```

At the end res will have the objects that you wanted, hope this helps :)